# Remove line spacing between variable columns

Tags: minipage, gap, line

I am using the following code which is resulting in line spacing problem. The first four may be long so they are separate but I need the last four in two columns. The problem is line gap between these two types.

[image]

Please suggest a way to remove the glaring problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}


    \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
        \textbf{Student Name:} James Weber Bond\\
        \textbf{Father's Name:} Brooke Bond\\
        \textbf{Programme:} Self Destruction with Specialization in Running Around\\
        \textbf{Enrollment Number:} IMX2014053\\    
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \textbf{Date of Birth:} 25/6/1965\\
        \textbf{Date of Admission:} 25/6/1985\\
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \textbf{Period of Programme:} 5 years\\
        \textbf{Duration of Programme:} 7 years\\
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Included complete source

Comment: the example you've provided isn't compilable -- we'd have to guess what document class and packages you are using.  however, the double backslash at the end of the last line of a column or a minipage will insert a blank line, and that is what you are probably referring to.  replace the `\\ ` in the first minipage by `\strut`.  there are no descenders on the last line, so when you remove the blank line, it may end up closer to the next line (from the next minipage) than you want; `\strut` adds the equivalent of descenders to deal with such a situation.

Comment: Sorry @barbarabeeton. I have add the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem here is the double backslash on the last line of the first minipage.
that inserts a blank line that you don't want.

since minipages, one above another, are set as close together as possible, the
absence of descenders (the part below the baseline of the letter "p" or "q") on the last line of the first minipage means that it will be too close to what comes
below it; add `\strut` at the end of the line to compensate.

with the document class you're using, a minipage will be indented by the default
paragraph indentation if it comes at the beginning of a line.  this is avoided
by starting the line with `\noindent`.  also, since you have defined the width
of the two minipages in the second group to be exactly half of the text width,
the space inserted between them by starting a new line with the second
`\begin{minipage}` will give you an overfull line warning.  get rid of this by
inserting a `%` to make this space be ignored.

the only relevant package (for this example) among the ones you've used is
`\geometry`.  for this answer, all the others have been omitted.

here is the "final" code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
        \textbf{Student Name:} James Weber Bond\\
        \textbf{Father's Name:} Brooke Bond\\
        \textbf{Programme:} Self Destruction with Specialization in Running Around\\
        \textbf{Enrollment Number:} IMX2014053\strut
    \end{minipage}

\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \textbf{Date of Birth:} 25/6/1965\\
        \textbf{Date of Admission:} 25/6/1985
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \textbf{Period of Programme:} 5 years\\
        \textbf{Duration of Programme:} 7 years
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 2):

I propose a very different way for realizing the student's sheet:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\student}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { xinit/student } { #1 }
  \xinit_student:
 }

\keys_define:nn { xinit/student }
 {
  student    .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_student_tl,
  father     .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_father_tl,
  programme  .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_programme_tl,
  enrollment .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_enrollment_tl,
  birth      .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_birth_tl,
  admission  .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_admission_tl,
  period     .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_period_tl,
  duration   .tl_set:N = \l_xinit_duration_tl,
  student    .value_required:n = true,
  father     .value_required:n = true,
  programme  .value_required:n = true,
  enrollment .value_required:n = true,
  birth      .value_required:n = true,
  admission  .value_required:n = true,
  period     .value_required:n = true,
  duration  .value_required:n = true,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xinit_student:
 {
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Student~Name}:~\l_xinit_student_tl} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Father's~Name}:~\l_xinit_father_tl} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Programme}:~\l_xinit_programme_tl} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Enrollment~Number}:~\l_xinit_enrollment_tl} \\
  \textbf{Date~of~Birth}:~\l_xinit_birth_tl &
  \textbf{Period~of~Programme}:~\l_xinit_period_tl \\
  \textbf{Date~of~Admission}:~\l_xinit_admission_tl &
  \textbf{Duration~of~Programme}:~\l_xinit_duration_tl
  \end{tabular*}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\student{
  student = James Weber Bond,
  father = Brooke Bond,
  programme = Self Destruction with Specialization in Running Around,
  enrollment = IMX2014053,
  birth = 25/6/1965,
  admission = 25/6/1985,
  period = 5 years,
  duration =  7 years,
}

\end{document}
```

By modifying the function `\xinit_student:` you can easily move around the items. The key-value pair method makes it easier to input the data, because the order is not fixed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg. I did not know of xparse and it will be very useful in some of my scripts.